# widget position and window size

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, spyder

I am new to GUI development and I am trying to learn how to use `pyqt5` in python.
Below is the example code I am working on. I want a window with some checkboxes,combobox and radiobuttons on the right side of the window. The details of the `QtWidget` objects are in the code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QPushButton, QComboBox, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 500
        self.title = 'Chip2 Torque Data'
        self.width = 500
        self.height =500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        xselect=QRadioButton("X",self)
        xselect.setChecked(True)

        xselect.move(340,400)
        zselect=QRadioButton("Z",self)
        zselect.move(380,400)
        sselect=QRadioButton("SP1",self)
        sselect.move(420,400)
        pass_list=QComboBox(self)
        pass_list.addItems(sheets_idealcut)
        pass_list.move(340,300)
        rawdata_check=QCheckBox("Raw Data",self)
        rawdata_check.setChecked(True)
        rawdata_check.move(340,200)
        mvgavg_check=QCheckBox("Moving average",self)
        mvgavg_check.setChecked(True)
        mvgavg_check.move(380,200)
        mvgstd_check=QCheckBox("Moving stdev",self)
        mvgstd_check.setChecked(True)
        mvgstd_check.move(420,200)
        self.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
　　sheets_idealcut=['pass2','pass3','pass4','pass5']

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
         app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))
    ex = App()
    #ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Below is the output of the code. (Please ignore the overlapping checkbox names. I intend to correct it later.)

[image]

My problem is when I maximise this window, the `QtWidget` objects(`QComboBox`,`QRadioButton`,`QCheckBox`) don't readjust their position with the new window size.
[image]

So for the widgets to reposition themselves automatically, what method should be used ?

I googled it but I couldn't find anything useful.

Please help.

Comment: You need to add the widgets to a [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: I had known about the layouts but I couldn't figure out how to adjust the position of a layout within the QMainwindow such that the layout is in the right side of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using layouts for dynamic sizing. There are alot of different layouts. The layouts used in this example is the most basic types. I also changed the parent of "App" to a QDialog. They are easier to handle.

Here is an example of your app, using layouts:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QPushButton, QComboBox, QRadioButton, \
QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 500
        self.title = 'Chip2 Torque Data'
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        xselect=QRadioButton("X",self)
        xselect.setChecked(True)
        # xselect.move(340,400)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(xselect)

        zselect=QRadioButton("Z",self)
        # zselect.move(380,400)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(zselect)

        sselect=QRadioButton("SP1",self)
        # sselect.move(420,400)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(sselect)



        pass_list=QComboBox(self)
        pass_list.addItems(sheets_idealcut)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(pass_list)
        #pass_list.move(340,300)
        rawdata_check=QCheckBox("Raw Data",self)
        rawdata_check.setChecked(True)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(rawdata_check)
        #rawdata_check.move(340,200)
        mvgavg_check=QCheckBox("Moving average",self)
        mvgavg_check.setChecked(True)
        #mvgavg_check.move(380,200)
        mvgstd_check=QCheckBox("Moving stdev",self)
        mvgstd_check.setChecked(True)
        #mvgstd_check.move(420,200)

        self.check_group = QHBoxLayout()
        self.check_group.addWidget(mvgavg_check)
        self.check_group.addWidget(mvgstd_check)
        self.check_group.stretch(1)

        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.check_group)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sheets_idealcut=['pass2','pass3','pass4','pass5']

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
         app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))
    ex = App()
    #ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `move(x,y)` which sets the Widgets to a specific fixed position. So you could write a function which is called on maximizing the window and then reposition your widgets accordingly.

Another automated approach is to use box layouts. `QtGui.QHBoxLayout` and `QtGui.QVBoxLayout` are basic layout classes which lines up widgets horizontally or vertically. From your pictures I do not know what exact positions you want your widgets to end up, so I try to explain it like I think you want it.

Each row of elements can be assigned into a HBox like this:

```
hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
hbox.addStretch(1)
hbox.addWidget(rawdata_check)
hbox.addWidget(mvgavg_check)
hbox.addWidget(mvgstd_check)
```

If you then resize the window the widgets should automaticly be repositioned to the right side of the window. The QtDesigner can help you arranging all the elements.